# Uninitialized constant Createcampaigns::LikeController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been struggling with adding the feature of Likes and Dis-likes. i have nested routes and I cant figure out what I am doing wrong:

My Routes looks like this

```
createcampaign_like_index GET    /createcampaigns/:createcampaign_id/like(.:format)              createcampaigns/like#index
                            POST   /createcampaigns/:createcampaign_id/like(.:format)              createcampaigns/like#create
    new_createcampaign_like GET    /createcampaigns/:createcampaign_id/like/new(.:format)          createcampaigns/like#new
   edit_createcampaign_like GET    /createcampaigns/:createcampaign_id/like/:id/edit(.:format)     createcampaigns/like#edit
        createcampaign_like GET    /createcampaigns/:createcampaign_id/like/:id(.:format)          createcampaigns/like#show
                            PATCH  /createcampaigns/:createcampaign_id/like/:id(.:format)          createcampaigns/like#update
                            PUT    /createcampaigns/:createcampaign_id/like/:id(.:format)          createcampaigns/like#update
                            DELETE      /createcampaigns/:createcampaign_id/like/:id(.:format)          createcampaigns/like#destroy



 resources :createcampaigns do
 resources :like, module: :createcampaigns
```

like controller

```
app/controllers/createcampaigns/likes_controller.rb
```

Content of my Like Controller.rb file

```
class Createcampaigns::LikesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!

  def likes

  end

  def index
     @createcampaign = Createcampaign.find(params[:createcampaign_id])
     @createcampaign.likes.where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create
     respond_with(@createcampaign)
  end

  def create
    @createcampaign.like.where(user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @createcampaign }
      format.js
    end
  end

  private

  def set_post
     @createcampaign = Createcampaign.find(params[:createcampaign_id])
  end
end
```

app/views/createcampaigns/show.html.erb

```
<div id="likes">
   <%= render partial: "likes" %>
</div>
```

user model

```
has_many :likes

 def likes?(post)
   post.likes.where(user_id: id).any?
 end
```

I tried first with this as the link:

```
<%= link_to "Like", createcampaign_like_path(@createcampaign), method: :like %>
```

I get this error

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Createcampaigns#show
  Showing /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views/createcampaigns/_like.html.erb         where line #2 raised:

  No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"createcampaigns/like",     :createcampaign_id=>#<Createcampaign id: 127, name: "Sessions must go; special prosecutor must be appoi...", description: "Attorney General Jeff Sessions lied under oath abo...", image: nil, location: "35 windfield ave", reason: "During his confirmation hearing, when asked by Sen...", bio: nil, user_id: 18, policy_in_question: nil, time: nil, contact_info: nil, city: "jersey city", state: "nj", zipcode: "07521", address: "3", country: "USA", banner: nil, created_at: "2017-03-15 14:44:04", updated_at: "2017-03-16 12:24:10", campaign_image: nil, campaignimage: "americanflag.jpg", eventgroundrules: nil, starts_at: nil, start_time: "4pm", campaigndate: "2017-03-15", campaigntarget: 0, admin: true, category_name: nil, category_id: 6, president_id: 743, senatemember_id: 1819, housemember_id: 1408>, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Extracted source (around line #2):

it seems it need or missing attributes so i tried passing in the user id and

```
 <%= link_to "Like", createcampaign_like_path(user_id: current_user.id), method: :like %>
```

i got this:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"createcampaigns/like", :id=>"127", :user_id=>16} missing required keys: [:createcampaign_id]
Extracted source (around line #2):
1
2
      <%= link_to "Like", createcampaign_like_path(user_id: current_user.id), method: :like %>
```

What should my routes be? please help.. New to rails must add

Comment: resources :createcampaigns do
  resources :likes, module: :createcampaigns
resources :comments,module: :createcampaigns
  resources :comments,module: :squeals
  resources :squeal,except: [:show,:index] 
    
    member do
     get :follow
      get :unfollow

    end
  end

Answer (score 0):

You need to post on this path

```
<%= link_to "Like", createcampaign_like_index_path(@createcampaign), method: :post %>
```

Check the routes you want to hit create action

```
createcampaign_like_index GET    /createcampaigns/:createcampaign_id/like(.:format)              createcampaigns/like#index
                          POST   /createcampaigns/:createcampaign_id/like(.:format)              createcampaigns/like#create
```

Also, I think you have something like this

```
resources :like
```

Change it to

```
resources :likes
```

Comment: resources :createcampaigns do
  resources :likes, module: :createcampaigns
resources :comments,module: :createcampaigns
  resources :comments,module: :squeals
  resources :squeal,except: [:show,:index] 
    
    member do
     get :follow
      get :unfollow

    end
  end